# Insert XSLT node-set B in another node-set A at detected position inside text node of node-set A

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to transform complex XML output of a content management system into XHTML. I'm using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` to get an XHTML fragment of whatever is described by XML input. That XML input comes with a very complex structure that may describe lots of different cases to be handled by several XSLT template elements. And that structure may change quite often in the future.

Previously, the resulting fragment of that transformation was directly sent to XSLT output. Now the requirements have changed and I need to capture result, occasionally modify it to insert some other well-formed XHTML fragment at a certain position in value of the fragment.

For the sake of demonstration, consider `<xsl:apply-templates/>` having created some opaque XHTML fragment captured in variable **container**.

```
<xsl:variable name="container">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:variable>
```

Next there is a second XHTML fragment in variable **snippet**:

```
<xsl:variable name="snippet">
  <xsl:call-template name="get-snippet" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Requirement says to have node-set in **$snippet** to be inserted before any optionally contained period at end of value of **$container**. This ain't problematic unless XHTML fragments in both variables have to be kept as fragments. Thus one can't operate on string values of either variable.

Is there any opportunity to achieve that requirement in XSLT without losing the power and flexibility of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` on retrieving XHTML fragment in **$container**?

BTW: I already know about accessing the last text node in `$container` using:

```
node-set($container)//child::text[last()]
```

But I missed to get something inserted in the mid of that text node and I consider XSLT failing to provide proper support for what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfContainer">
  <html>
   <p>Hello, world.</p>
   <p> This is <b>just</b> a <i>demo.</i></p>
   <p> Of some text</p>
  </html>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vContainer" select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfContainer)/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfSnippet">
   <p>Snippet</p>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vSnippet" select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfSnippet)/*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vText" select=
  "($vContainer//text()[contains(.,'.')])[last()]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vContainer"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(generate-id() = generate-id($vText))">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:call-template name="insertSnippet">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vText"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="insertSnippet">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>

    <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before($pText, '.')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vTail" select=
         "substring-after($pText, '.')"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains(substring($vTail,2), '.'))">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vSnippet"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('.', $vTail)"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="insertSnippet">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText"
      select="substring-after($pText, '.')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied (to any XML document -- not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <p>Hello, world.</p>
   <p> This is <b>just</b> a <i>demo
         <p>Snippet</p>.</i></p>
   <p> Of some text</p>
</html>
```

**Explanation**: Identity rule overriden by a recursive named template to find the last `'.'` in a string.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vContainer">
  <html>
   <p>Hello, world.</p>
   <p> This is <b>just</b> a <i>demo.</i></p>
   <p> Of some text</p>
  </html>
 </xsl:variable>


 <xsl:variable name="vSnippet">
   <p>Snippet</p>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vText" select=
  "($vContainer//text()[contains(.,'.')])[last()]"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vContainer/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[. is $vText]">
  <xsl:variable name="vInd" select=
   "index-of(string-to-codepoints(.), string-to-codepoints('.'))[last()]"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="substring(., 1, $vInd -1)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$vSnippet/*"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="substring(., $vInd)"></xsl:sequence>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is performed, again the wanted correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <p>Hello, world.</p>
   <p> This is <b>just</b> a <i>demo
         <p>Snippet</p>.</i></p>
   <p> Of some text</p>
</html>
```

**Explanation**: Use of the standard XPath 2.0 functions `string-to-codepoints()`, `index-of()`, `substring()` and operator `is`.